# Solaris 7 DHCP Client

Tags: networking, solaris, qemu, dhcp, sparc

I am running Solaris 7 on qemu-sparc with lance ethernet card. In case with Linux starting dhcpcd is enough to get the Internet access. OK, I created /etc/dhcp.le0, network interface is up, but "ping google.com" results in "unknown host". What I forgot to do?

Comment: What happens if you ping an IP address instead of a hostname?

Comment: Something like "icmp from gateway unknown (10.0.2.15) to (IP_address): destination unreachable". 10.0.2.15 was the IP address I set  while I was installing system onto the hard disk, because there was no "Use DHCP" switch.

Comment: Holy moly.  Solaris 7.  End of life, end of support back in 2008.  Hope you're on a trusted network here, vulnerabilities galore.

Answer (score 1):

From the error of "unknown host" it sounds like you don't have a DNS server set. If you could, check the files /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/resolv.conf . nsswitch.conf should have a line like: `hosts: files dns` and resolv.conf should have a line like: `nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` where the x's are the IP address of your DNS server.

The nsswitch.conf instructs the OS where to look for certain things (in this case, hostname to IP address mapping) and the resolv.conf specifies what server the networking service should look to for DNS lookups. One would hope DHCP is setting a name server, but it is good to make sure.

Comment: DNS Server should be 8.8.8.8 (Google Public DNS)?

Comment: That would work. Are you able to ping 8.8.8.8?